# ElasticSearch sorting on specfic values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elasticsearch, nest

I want to sort result from Elastic based on a field value.

```
  Document Type Hierarchy:
  1) Type1
  2) Type2
  3) Type3
  4) Type4
```

I m using the following query in ElasticsearchHead Chrome extension

```
 http://localhost:9200/products/_search [Post]


{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "ispublished": "1"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1000,
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "script": {
          "lang": "groovy",
          "inline": "if(doc['type']=='Type1') return 1; elseif(doc['type']=='Type2') return 2;else return 0;"
        },
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "aggs": {}
}
```

But I m getting the following error

```
    {
"error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[Qx2ykny3RSmMOoGCdR-MQQ][endscompliance][0]: SearchParseException[[endscompliance][0]: query[+ispublished:1],from[0],size[1000]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"ispublished":"1"}}],"must_not":[],"should":[]}},"from":0,"size":1000,"sort":[{"_script":{"type":"number","script":{"lang":"groovy","inline":"if(doc['type']=='Type1') return 1; elseif(doc['type']=='Type2') return 2;else return 0;"},"order":"asc"}}],"aggs":{}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[endscompliance][0]: query[+ispublished:1],from[0],size[1000]: Parse Failure [_script sorting requires setting the script to sort by]]; }{[Qx2ykny3RSmMOoGCdR-MQQ][endscompliance][1]: SearchParseException[[endscompliance][1]: query[+ispublished:1],from[0],size[1000]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"ispublished":"1"}}],"must_not":[],"should":[]}},"from":0,"size":1000,"sort":[{"_script":{"type":"number","script":{"lang":"groovy","inline":"if(doc['type']=='Type1') return 1; elseif(doc['type']=='Type2') return 2;else return 0;"},"order":"asc"}}],"aggs":{}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[endscompliance][1]: query[+ispublished:1],from[0],size[1000]: Parse Failure [_script sorting requires setting the script to sort by]]; }{[Qx2ykny3RSmMOoGCdR-MQQ][endscompliance][2]: SearchParseException[[endscompliance][2]: query[+ispublished:1],from[0],size[1000]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"ispublished":"1"}}],"must_not":[],"should":[]}},"from":0,"size":1000,"sort":[{"_script":{"type":"number","script":{"lang":"groovy","inline":"if(doc['type']=='Type1') return 1; elseif(doc['type']=='Type2') return 2;else return 0;"},"order":"asc"}}],"aggs":{}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[endscompliance][2]: query[+ispublished:1],from[0],size[1000]: Parse Failure [_script sorting requires setting the script to sort by]]; }{[Qx2ykny3RSmMOoGCdR-MQQ][endscompliance][3]: SearchParseException[[endscompliance][3]: query[+ispublished:1],from[0],size[1000]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"ispublished":"1"}}],"must_not":[],"should":[]}},"from":0,"size":1000,"sort":[{"_script":{"type":"number","script":{"lang":"groovy","inline":"if(doc['type']=='Type1') return 1; elseif(doc['type']=='Type2') return 2;else return 0;"},"order":"asc"}}],"aggs":{}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[endscompliance][3]: query[+ispublished:1],from[0],size[1000]: Parse Failure [_script sorting requires setting the script to sort by]]; }{[Qx2ykny3RSmMOoGCdR-MQQ][endscompliance][4]: SearchParseException[[endscompliance][4]: query[+ispublished:1],from[0],size[1000]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"ispublished":"1"}}],"must_not":[],"should":[]}},"from":0,"size":1000,"sort":[{"_script":{"type":"number","script":{"lang":"groovy","inline":"if(doc['type']=='Type1') return 1; elseif(doc['type']=='Type2') return 2;else return 0;"},"order":"asc"}}],"aggs":{}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[endscompliance][4]: query[+ispublished:1],from[0],size[1000]: Parse Failure [_script sorting requires setting the script to sort by]]; }]",
"status": 400
}
```

Elastic version is 1.7.5

Nest version is 5.5

Comment: You'll need to use NEST 1.x with Elasticsearch 1.x

Comment: Elastic version is 1.7.5 and Nest version is 5.5

Comment: Take a look at the client -> Elasticsearch compatibility matrix: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net#compatibility-matrix. NEST 5.x is not tested with or supported against Elasticsearch 1.x. It may work for the most part, but breaking changes are likely to result in exceptions. As an example, Painless scripting language is not supported in Elasticsearch 1.x because it was only introduced in Elasticsearch 5.x

Comment: ok @RussCam any alternate solution to this?

Comment: You should be able to perform this kind of script sorting with a scripting language that 1.x supports e.g. Groovy, and the NEST 1.x client

Comment: 'groovy' also giving the same error

Comment: Can you please update your question and provide more information e.g. update the query to show the one you're now using, the NEST API call that you're making, the JSON response from Elasticsearch, etc.

Comment: Your query is invalid for Elasticsearch 1.x. Take a look at the 1.x documentation on Script Based Sorting: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting. `"script"` should be a `string` as opposed to an `object`. You should also check that `doc['type']` is not null, and use `doc['type'].value`

Comment: I m getting this error now `ScriptException[scripts of type [inline], operation [search] and lang [groovy] are disabled]; }]",`

Comment: It sounds like dynamic scripting is disabled on the cluster. If you wish to use a non-sandboxed scripting language like Groovy, you need to enable this in configuration. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting

Comment: Hmm...this is something I cannot go with, @RussCam I m thinking to use another field to store numbers for types like 'TypeID' with values like Type1=1 Type2=2 Type3=3 and then sort on 'TypeID' field, what you think is it good to go with?

Comment: That would work - just need to ensure that those two properties are always in sync